# Why am I getting a no-method-error with this twitter-like rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship

I am making a rails application where people can follow other people.  I have about 100 users I faked in the database.  I used the faker gem to upload fake users and fake relationships to the database with this code:

```
def make_relationships
  users = User.all
  user  = users.first
  followed_users = users[2..50]
  followers      = users[3..40]
  followed_users.each { |followed| user.follow!(followed) }
  followers.each      { |follower| follower.follow!(user) }
end
```

That should make user 1 follow users 2-50 and user 1 be followed by users 3-40.  However, I don't think this is happening.  When i visit the profile page of users 3-51, It displays the "unfollow" button, meaning all of these users are being followed by 1.  I am not sure why 51 is included in this.  For some reason, when I go to the profile of user 2 or any user above 51, I get:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for(current_user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(@user.id)) do |f| %>
2:   <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
3:   <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
4: <% end %>
```

Can someone tell me why I can't access any of the profile pages above 51?  Here is the rest of the relavent code:

Relationship model:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :followed_id, :follower_id

  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"

  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

User model:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy

 has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
 has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed

 has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id", class_name: "Relationship", dependent: :destroy
 has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower
 attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_token
```

Follow view partial:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(@user.id)) do |f| %>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
    <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Unfollow view partial:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(@user),
    html: {method: :delete}) do |f| %>
    <%=f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-large" %>
<% end %>
```

Follow Form that renders the two partials above:

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
  <div id="follow_form">
  <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
    <%= render 'unfollow' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'follow' %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

By the way, this is from the Michael Hardtl tutorial if that can help anyone solve this.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?  I still can't figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message the current_user object you're passing is most likely nil

Comment: I don't see how that could be.  Current_user is working on pages below 50 and it doesn't change from page to page.